# I'm having a problem with navbar mobile view

Tags: html, css

My navbar, although it looks responsive, has a problem with the mobile view:

[image: screenshot navbar]

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" of your code to this question, Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we might need to know how your code is looking at the moment but apparently most navs that use an unorganized list and have the same effect that yours, which is to spread text from left to right, I think should look something like this:

```
<nav>
<button>Button</button>
<ul>
<li>home</li>
<li>about</li>
<li>contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
} 

ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-content: center;
}

li {
margin: 12px;
padding: 8px;
color: white;
}

button {
height: 80px;
width: 100px;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 1rem;
}
```

I mean something close to this but typically that is a standard alignment for the most part.